# Typescript create new map<String, List<String>>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hashmap

I'm trying to create a new Map in Typescript like this:
Map<String, List < String > >.
Something like (this example is in java):

```
private map<String, List<String>> map = HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>();
```

Until now my code is:

```
myMap=new Map();
```

I tried different approaches but it doesn't work. How it can be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
const categoryMap = new Map<string, string[]>();
```

or

```js
const categoryMap: Map<string, string[]> = new Map();
```